# Some scheduled tasks failing with error: Connection Failure: Status code unavailable

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfadmin

I've googled the issue and pretty much every answer has been related to a certificate issue.  Problem is, we have other tasks on the same server that trigger just fine.  The file runs as expected directly from a browser, so it's not an issue in the CF code. And with other scheduled tasks running fine I don't see it being a problem with any certificate.  Any suggestions on what else could cause this?

From the log:

```
 Information [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9] - MyTask - myreport triggered.

 Information [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9] - Starting HTTP request {URL='http://myserver/reports/myreport.cfm', method='get'}

 Error [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9] - Connection Failure: Status code unavailable
```

Comment: It can't be a certificate issue, because your task URL is HTTP, so there are no certificates involved.

Comment: Whatever it is, does it rely on Javascript?

Comment: No, it just runs a basic query then sends an email.  Issue also seems isolated to our development server and not on production.

Comment: I would try pinging or accessing that URL directly from the server. It could be that your scheduled task server cannot resolve that request. If the server where the task is being ran is the same server as the task itself, you might need to call the URL from localhost.

Comment: are your others tasks hitting the same domain and with "http" and not "https"? For example maybe there is a local dns issue for the domain or only https is allowed but this one is being hit with http

Comment: Both tasks are HTTP (no TLS/SSL) and the tasks are on the same server. We tried using 127.0.0.1 and the server's IP but get the same error.  I checked the permissions were the same on the two files.

Comment: I think I've narrowed it down to a possible directory access issue. It's only allowing us to run scripts from a particular directory and not the root of our html directory.

Comment: Not a huge deal, as a certain someone should be running scripts from the specific directory anyway, but now I'm jus curious where this would be set.

Comment: Re-register the scheduled task with HTTPS in place of HTTP.